# Python - concatenated value that generates shouldn't generates a new line

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I am reading the values from a text file, and giving them a format that my boss asked. It should be something like this:

> Max-Stock-Multiplier-ALL          0.001200 Between 0.000000 10000.000000

The "0.0012" value is the part that I'm reading from the file.It has other several lines where I did the same, but only in this one the result is:

> Max-Stock-Multiplier-ALL          0.001200
>
> Between 0.000000 10000.000000

So, my code is this

```
newline1 = "Target-Stock-Multiplier-ALL  %s Between 0.000000 10000.000000\n" % (line[37])
```

What's the error I'm making??

Comment: Does line[37] contain a newline character?

Comment: When I checked it with print, it just showed 0.0012, all the previous numbers are the same.

Comment: you are getting the new line at the end of the `line[]` object

Comment: is there a way to remove it?

Comment: mystring = mystring.replace('\n', '')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a newline character in `line[37]`. Simply remove it with `strip`:

```
newline1 = "Target-Stock-Multiplier-ALL  %s Between 0.000000 10000.000000\n" % (line[37].strip('\n'))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about strip